# How can I search for a specific phrase that includes a dash?

Tags: discussion, bug, search

I'm searching for `"strings -n"` but none of the 90 results are pages that include `"strings -n"`

I'm doing the search wrong? Or is this happening because I have to escape `-`?

I tried searching `"strings \-n"` but that didn't work.

I initially tried this with `"strings -n" [xcode]`. That just returned 1005 results that again didn't include `"strings -n"`

Comment: You could also use a general search engine, they often work much better than the search integrated in SO: For example in Google you can use `"strings -n" xcode site:stackoverflow.com`, other engines may also work with the `site:` part.

Comment: That ^ but generally, avoid using SO's internal search. It's garbage for symbols. You'll find a lot better results by using Ecosia, DuckDuckGo, Google, or generally your favorite search engine.

Comment: @Tom hah. Thought I initially tried that. ie In Chrome, I typed stackoverflow.com but before finishing my typing, Chrome offered autocomplete. I hit `tab` and then Chrome turns the text color blueish. I typed my query, thinking it would be routed through Google's search engine. Yet it just redirected me to this URL: `https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=strings+-n`. Anyhow I tried what you said and got only **1 result** along with other results that didn't find "strings -n". While that's definitely helpful, I feel like that's an _alternate_ solution

Comment: Mhh,  strange, I get several pages full of results.

Comment: @Tom I get too. But only one of the links actually includes a correct result.The other links don't actually contain `strings -n`. Does any of your other links contain a correct substring?

Comment: Some of them :D., but the search still is pretty lenient with the results, even when we're using quotes, so it also lists stuff like `strings[n]` or `strings: \n`. A bit disappointing.

Comment: @philipxy I did look in the 'Search help' but not sure what you mean. Are you talking about doing `body: "strings -n"` that didn't work. Nor I see it necessary for other places were searching just works if I wrap in double quotes.

Comment: "The default SE search doesn't look at code." If you don't see it in the quick & advanced helps you can google for a SE question about it.

Comment: @philipxy  "The default SE search doesn't look at code." doesn't seem correct. Try searching for `func inspect (value1: T, value2: T) {`. You will find my answer among the 3 results. `func inspect (value1: T, value2: T) {` is only written in code.

Comment: I expect that code aspects of SO/SE search & its documentation change without notice. See google hits about it to get some idea. (Which you should have done before considering posting this.)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296120/why-is-code-excluded-from-phrase-search There aren't any mentions of code search per se on the canonical SE features updates post. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange